# UnsatisfiedLinkError on iOS but not Android, loadLibrary always succeeds

Tags: java, c++, libgdx, java-native-interface

I have some Java and C++ code that I can compile on both platforms and build native libraries. I can verify that the libraries contain the functions I expect, and Java is able to load the libraries on Android and iOS. On Android everything goes smoothly with no crash, but on iOS I get a very frustrating error:

```
2015-05-11 11:34:48.418 IOSLauncher[52454:851038] [info] test: initializing native libraries...
2015-05-11 11:34:48.418 IOSLauncher[52454:851038] [info] test: library path set to:       "/Users/test/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A189459D-B2D5-4E78-A6E4-A7EAD19DA017/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DF265D55-DA3C-4C10-851D-20591C4C8C06/IOSLauncher.app"
2015-05-11 11:34:48.419 IOSLauncher[52454:851038] [info] test: loading native libraries on x86_64...
2015-05-11 11:34:48.419 IOSLauncher[52454:851038] [info] test:  test
2015-05-11 11:34:48.424 IOSLauncher[52454:851038] [info] test: loaded libraries successfully

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/test/Native.getPointer()J
    at com.test.Native.getPointer(Native Method)
    at com.test.WavApp.initNativeEngine(WavApp.java)
    at com.test.WavApp.create(WavApp.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.$cb$drawRect$(IOSGraphics.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at com.test.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 18.262 secs
```

A snapshot of the java code in com/test/Native.java:

```
static 
{
      System.loadLibrary("test");
      Log.i("loaded libraries successfully");
}

public static native long getPointer();
public static native void freePointer(long enginePointer);
```

And the C++ code that compiles into `libtest.dylib`:

```
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_getPointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
    {
        return (jlong)(new PointerTest());
    }

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_freePointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
        jlong enginePtr)
    {
        if ((PointerTest*)enginePtr)
            delete (PointerTest*)enginePtr;
    }
}
```

Some more info about the built shared library:

```
Release$ file libtest.dylib
libtest.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

And verifying the exports:

```
$ nm -g libtest.dylib | grep Native
0000000000011ce0 T _Java_com_test_Native_freePointer
0000000000011c40 T _Java_com_test_Native_getPointer
```

Any ideas? This has been driving me crazy for hours. I can reproduce this error on my Android device by simply using a different library and searching for that function. I'm guessing xcode is somehow hiding or stripping the symbols, but that doesn't seem to correlate with my `nm` output above which shows they are there.

Comment: Do you use robovm ? If so, make sure that its version is compatible with libgdx version that you use.

Comment: Yes, I use RoboVM and have it updated to the latest. I will look into this.

Comment: It's just an idea, but your file call shows that libtest.dylib is a X86_64 binary while ios runs (as far as I know) on ARM processors. May that be the problem?

Comment: I had a problem with robovm. [More specifcally this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865730/how-to-install-earlier-version-of-robovm-eclipse-plugin). So, the trick is not to have the latest the greatest version of robovm, but having correct version of it for IOS and using mathcing libgdx version.

Comment: Can't check now, but if it works later you will collect the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in front of me, as usual, in this line:

```
libtest.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Building for iOS, the architecture should be armv7+. Misconfigured xcode subproject.