# How to install earlier version of robovm eclipse plugin?

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I have been working on a game project using libgdx. My dev environment is as follows:

**OS:**
Mac OSX 10.10.3

**IDE:**
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

**With**
Robovm eclipse plugin.

**ibgdx version:**
1.4.1

I have had "auto updates on" through out my development process and it worked well until April 2015 (more or less until robovm 1.2 release I think).

I was able to produce ad-hoc releases and get my testers install the app via installrapp.com before April'15. I needed to take a break from this project to work on something else for a while.When I came back to it a week ago to make a release of the game, there was a robovm update and things started to fall apart afterwards. Robovm got bumped up to 1.3, which caused compilation errors in source code. I tried o upgrade libgdx to 1.6.2 but it didn't help at all. I am almost at release phase and I do NOT want to deal with code changes at all, not to exhaust my testers.

I restored my project+eclipse installation from an earlier backup I have. But unfortunately, robovm plugin version in my backup is 1.2. Although I can produce IPAs using it, my testers say, app crashes right after splash screen.

Although I have seen [this post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17309), I think robovm 1.2 plugin is the suspect for my case.

What I am looking forward to do is to find a way to re-install robovm 1.0.0 plugin. I found the source code of it [here](https://github.com/robovm/robovm-eclipse/releases/tag/robovm-eclipse-1.0.0.201502121855).

But I don't know how to build it.

I could not find binary version of plugin available anywhere. When I tried to install it within eclipse, unfortunately only the latest version of the plugin is available.

How could I downgrade robovm eclipse plugin ?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I noticed that IPAs generated by robovm work on IOS 7.1.2 but not on IOS 8.3 .

Comment: The plugin and the robovm version must match. Make sure you update both in your build.gradle.

Comment: Yes, I know. They used to match perfectly and I confirm here that robovm ,and IPAs I created using it, used to work well. But I had auto-updates on in eclipse, so robovm plugin got updated. That's the cause of this havoc.Trying to find a way to downgrade robovm plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I dug more around, I found some stuff. I am going to share my findings here so that, perhaps, someone else can benefit from.

First of all, older binary versions of robovm plugin could be found [here](http://download.robovm.org/).

Just download the required version, unarchive it (if necessary) and add it to your eclipse via a local resource. I managed to install robovm.1.0.0.

However it did NOT help my case. But while I was poking here and there, I have noticed that IPAs work on IOS 7.1.2 but crash on IOS 8.3.

This made me think that IOS 8.3 has some tricks (as usual) and newer version of robovm is required to make apps working on that platform. This posting [here](http://robovm.com/robovm-1-1-released-interface-builder-support/) proves that theory.

What it means for me is the fact that I need to update robovm to get my app working on IOS 8.3. In order to get robovm working with libgdx etc, I also need to update bunch of other tools (find versions of tools [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/versions.html)) and possibly tackle compilation errors.

I am not sure if these will fix the problems I am facing with. I will update here when I am done with them.

**__UPDATE__**

After fussing and fighting with trying to get everything up-to-date, I decided to start from scratch instead. Here is what I have done:

- I got the lastest STS bundle
- I added graddle on top of it
- Added android SDK plugin for eclipse
- Added Robovm latest plugin
- I downloaded the latest libgdx installer
- Craeted a new project using GUI utility
- Created Android and IOS projects.
- Confirmed that IOS project works fine on IOS8 & IOS7.
- Confirmed that android project works fine
- I migrated my code over to new project.
- Confirmed that IOS project works on both IOS7 & IOS8 (both simulator and device)
- Android project works on device

It was a bit heavy-handed solution but it worked.!

I hope these help someone else besides me.